# Best Method for Debugging CluedIn Integration Locally

Tags: vscode-debugger, cluedin

I've been working on multiple integrations with CluedIn.  They are installed in a local Docker instance but I'm having a hard time understanding how to setup the debugging process in Visual Studio Code.

I've loaded the package .dll and .pdb files into the /app/ServerComponents folder on the cluedin_default_server_1 container.

How do I attach a debugger to the CluedIn integrations for debugging?

Answer (score 1):

This may require extra steps to debug with Visual Studio Code, but with Visual Studio this should be simple.

Assuming that you are using the `default` environment:

**Install procps into `cluedin_default_server_1` container.**

You have to attach as a root. To do so, either change the `docker-compose.server.yaml` and add `user: root` after `server:` like this:

```yaml
  server:
    user: root
```

Or you can just attach from the command line as a root:
`docker exec -it --user root cluedin_default_server_1 /bin/sh`

When you are in the container's shell, please, run: `apk add procps`.

**Copy the DLLs and PDBs**

Build your solution and copy the DLLs and PDBs under `\Home\env\default\components\ServerComponent` (the `default` is the name of your environment).

**Restart or recreate the container**

`docker container restart cluedin_default_server_1`
If this will not work, please, try to delete the container and run `.\cluedin.ps1 up` - it will create a new container for you.

**Attach to the process from Visual Studio**

In Visual Studio, hit `Ctrl+Alt+P` or go to Debug -> Attach to Process...

Select the Docker connection type and the container you want to debug, and then the `dotnet` process. The process must be `dotnet exec ... --Name ServerComponent`.

[image]

Click Attach and check the Managed checkbox:

[image]

Now you should be able to debug your code.